# Kivy Dynamic selection image according to button

Tags: python, kivy

I want to place image on button. Button's size depends on size of screen. I want to select ideal image's size according to button's size. Buttons are defined in class ButtonTools. With my knowledges I cann obtain size only in fuction of class ButtonTools. How do I obtain size of screen?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.uix.image import Image


class Paint(Widget):
    pass

class ButtonTools(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ButtonTools, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.size_hint = (1, None)
        self.height = 50


        but = Button(on_press = self.DrawAbscissa)
        but.background_normal = 'abscissa.png'
        self.add_widget(but)

        but = Button( on_press = self.DrawCurve)
        but.background_normal ='curve.png'
        self.add_widget(but)


    def DrawAbscissa(self, obj):
        size = self.parent.size
        p=1
        pass

    def DrawCurve(self, obj):
        pass

class WorkShop(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WorkShop, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"

        self.paint = Paint()

        self.tools = ButtonTools()

        self.add_widget(self.paint)
        self.add_widget(self.tools)

class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return WorkShop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the screen size using the following:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
...
        print("Window.size={}".format(Window.size))
        print("Window.height={}".format(Window.height))
        print("Window.width={}".format(Window.width))
```

Comment: Thank You! I apply your advice immediately now.